# C# SSL 3.0 (TCP) Protocol Decryption?

Tags: c#

I am trying to read packets from a protocol (AIM 7) that has SSL encryption, how would I take the SSL off using C#?

Thanks.

I don't want extra dll's in my applications, which is why I'm trying to write it from the ground up. It is complicated to do, but I want to create a client by analyzing the packets aim 7 is sending across the network (with a proxy) and decode them, then re-encode them and create my own client without using dll's created by them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `SslStream`. Wrap the `TcpClient.GetStream()` with it.

Comment: I think @Eric wants to intercept and decrypt an SSL conversation that his application did not establish.  Can SslStream really do this?

Comment: no. I think that @Eric want to act as a proxy that pretends to be the AIM client. Hence it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in theory but not very practical.  You would need access to data available only in the AIM process (the current symmetric key for the conversation which is constantly changing).  If you are trying to decrypt an SSL conversation in which your computer is not participating then consider it impossible (this is the whole point of using SSL).  Either way you are either trying to hack something or going about something the wrong way.  Perhaps you can tell us what you are trying to accomplish?  Using the AIM API as it was intended or using the Windows API to control an instance of AIM is a much easier way to write an application that "speaks" AIM.

Comment: I don't want extra dll's in my applications, which is why I'm trying to write it from the ground up. It is complicated to do, but I want to create a client by analyzing the packets aim 7 is sending across the network (with a proxy) and decode them, then re-encode them and create my own client without using dll's created by them.

Comment: Ah, I see.  That's going to be a giant pain I'm afraid.  There is a lot of (unofficial) documentation out there for the different AIM protocols but since it's proprietary nothing out there is perfect.  To decrypt the SSL stream you need either the symmetric key pairs as they change or the private key for AOL's SSL certificate which is never transmitted over the wire.  There are some nice SSL decryption tools available for troubleshooting purposes that work with Wireshark but without the originating certificate with private key it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is shipping extra DLL's, you can merge assemblies and then use a third party SSL library that you merge with your application and only ship it as a single assembly.

You use ILMerge to do this.